# symbols allowed in rss file

Tags: php

which symbols are allowed in rss file? 
Maybe is some pattern, or special function (php) which clean text?

Comment: RSS = XML, so would fall under the same rules.

Comment: Voting to close because this is too broad a question. RSS is a defined format, you can read up on the various specifications that will tell you what the format needs to look like. If you have a specific question about allowed characters, please add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Well Formed XML inside RSS. `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` should work to prepare the string. (presuming you're dealing with UTF-8)

http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: Hi Pekka, please educate me. With UTF-8 how can the parser determine the difference between < in text, and < that represents the start of a tag? Thanks!

Comment: My comment made much more sense before yours was edited and changed completely. It was intended at your comment that characters didn't need to be encoded when using UTF-8.

Comment: If you're going to have `<` `>` as non-tags in your XML, you wrap it in `<![CDATA[]]>` of course